# All possible solutions to $x^y = 8$ and $y^x = 9$

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I know the obvious solution $(x,y)=(2,3)$. I just want to know if there are any other solutions to above system of equations or is $(x,y)=(2,3)$ the only solution. Also, both $x$ and $y$ should be real numbers.

Please provide a method to solve equations like these if it exists.

Comment: you asking just for rational and integers or for real numbers in general?

Comment: @Ahmad Real numbers in general. I will update the question.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5Ey%3D8+vs+y%5Ex%3D9&x=0&y=0) says it's probably the only one.

Comment: I would recommend either plotting the functions to find their intercept (s) or applying logarithms to each equation to obtain something that gives x in terms of some function of y.

Comment: @ Prakhar Dwivedi well, you have two equation with two variables and because the $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ is one-to-one functions in the Real domain there is one solution. if you allow $x,y$ to be complex numbers then because $\ln(x),e^x$ are periodic function in the complex domain,i think there could by more than one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote it as a comment but i will complete it now ,

well, you have two equation with two variables and because the $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ is one-to-one functions in the Real domain there is one solution. if you allow $x,y$ to be complex numbers then because $\ln(x),e^x$ are periodic function in the complex domain,i think there could by more than one answer.(actually infinitely many)

for instance : take $x=1+i$ then for all $y=\frac{i \left(2 \pi  c-3 i \log (2)\right)}{\log (1+i)}$ for any integer $c$.

hope its what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 2):

if you take the logarithm on both sides we get
$$y\ln(x)=\ln(8)$$ and $$x\ln(y)=\ln(9)$$ from here we get
$$y\ln\left(\frac{\ln(9)}{\ln(y)}\right)=\ln(8)$$ and here you must use a numerical method.